# Weird Browser behaviour in ExpressJS application , On closing and reopening tab HTML code is displayed , on reloading works well

Tags: node.js, apache, browser, express, browser-cache

[image]

My expressJS application is showing some weird behaviour and its doing every time I repeat the following steps.

1. Open the link in the browser.
2. Go to some other tab and close the tab with my website link previously opened.
3. Open another tab and open exact same link of my website.
4. It shows the content of the image, no matter how long you wait.
5. Reload and it works well.

Same behaviour in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

I have tried disabling etag and disabling cache but doesnt seem to help. Any idea?
One more update :

> Might be because of apache , local env do not do this , only deployed
>   one does .

Answer (score 0):

There seemed to be a problem with the redirect , I removed the redirect and rendered the page expected .
Its a work around , the reason of the problem persists , if someone else gets struck at similar problem , this might be one solution .